# Error upon attempt deploy React.js project on GitLab

Tags: reactjs, git, gitlab

I'm push my code in GitLab and everything pushed ok, but when I try deploy my React.js project to GitLab, but got next error:

[image]

Early i'm deployed this project on GitHub and everything was ok

my package.json code:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://groupname.gitlab.io/projectName/",
  "dependencies": {
    "ellipsis-tooltip-react-chan": "^1.1.1",
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
    "modal-simple": "^1.0.19",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "paginering": "^1.0.6",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "reactjs-popup": "^2.0.4",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "predeploy": "npm run build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

my .gitlab-ci.yml file

i'm found this solution on GitHub, but it's not work to me

```
image: node:7.9.0 # change to match your node version

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

before_script:
  - npm install

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - CI=true npm test

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - CI=true npm run build
    - rm -rf public
    - mv build public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public # GitLab pages serve from a 'public' directory
  only:
    - master # run on master branch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. It was happening because my real node (npm) version was not like in my .gitlab-ci.yml file.

Needed print `node --version` in the terminal and it display my current version of node (in my case it was 12.18.3)

I change my .gitlab-ci.yml file to

```
image: node:12.18.3 # change to match your project's node version

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

before_script:
  - rm -rf build
  - CI=false npm install

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - CI=false npm run build
    - rm -rf public
    - cp build/index.html build/404.html
    - mv build public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - master
```

And everything was deployed